# Get iFrame ID on-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have used the following `iframe` in my website

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery('#video1').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
</script>

<iframe id="video1" width="520" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TJ2X4dFhAC0?enablejsapi" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to get the `id` of the `iframe` onclick of the iframe video, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This seems crazy that getting the value of a tag by accessing it from the same. I don't know what you are doing this. If you have many iframes then you can say that I want to get the id of iframe which is clicked. Well for single you can do this

```
  $('#video1').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
```

Comment: Not working. Nothing get alert on click the iframe just the video is playing.

Comment: @SamHanson dear go to firebug, and check console tab and see if there is an error of javascript?

Comment: The following error appears ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$('#video1').click(function(){ and Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Comment: You have not included jquery file, if you have included use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Show me your code that you are using?

Comment: @SamHanson hi in my country youtube is not working. do one trick. Wrap the iframe in any div and give `video` as id to that wraping div some thing like `<div='video1'><iframe src=""..></iframe></div>`. dont give any id to iframe and check.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have multiple iframes and so the goal is to determine which one they clicked on?  If so, this should work:

```
$(function() { //Attach to the jquery onLoad function
    $('iframe').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).id;
        console.log(id);
        // do stuff with id here
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not working for me. If i click the iframe just the video is playing. I have alert a text inside the function. But it's not working.

Comment: Can you us what you are trying to achieve? It does appear to be prohibited to handle the click event of an iframe loading an external URL, but perhaps there is another way to solve your problem. For example. If you use the Youtube Javascript API to embed videos, you can attach to the onStateChange event and fire an event whenever videos are started, stopped, etc.

Answer (score -2):

```
onclick='call(this)'
```

In javascript

```
function call(ev)
{
alert(ev.id)
}
```

In jquery

```
function call(ev)
{
alert($(ev).attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: This will not work, there is no `onclick` for the iframe tag:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp